Debug simultaneously when developing a Maui cross-platform app in Visual Studio
I'm working on cross-platform development through .NET MAUI using Visual Studio.
There is no difficulty in debugging each through Windows Application or Android Emulator.
However, I would like to check with the emulator and Windows application at the same time how it affected through Hot reload after modifying the code.
So, Is there any way to do debugging at the same time?

I think it's apporachable according to your description. See Reload on multiple platforms:

XAML Hot Reload supports simultaneous debugging of multiple platforms
in Visual Studio and Visual Studio for Mac, provided that you have
separate head projects per platform rather than a single project app.
For example, you can deploy an Android and an iOS target at the same
time to see your changes reflected on both platforms at once. To debug
on multiple platforms on Windows, see How To: Set multiple startup
projects. To debug on multiple platforms on a Mac, see Set multiple
startup projects.

